# custom taxonomy - Template not working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

I have custom post type and custom taxonomy but my template is not working:
**CustomPostType**

```
add_action('init', 'registerCustomPostTypes');
function registerCustomPostTypes() {
    register_post_type('product', [
        'labels' => [
            'name'               => __('Produkty'),
            'singular_name'      => __('Produkt'),
            'menu_name'          => __('Produkty'),
            'name_admin_bar'     => __('Produkt'),
            'add_new'            => __('Dodaj nowy'),
            'add_new_item'       => __('Dodaj nowy produkt'),
            'edit_item'          => __('Edytuj produkt'),
            'new_item'           => __('Nowy produkt'),
            'view_item'          => __('Zobacz produkt'),
            'search_items'       => __('Przeszukaj bazę produktów'),
            'not_found'          => __('Nie znaleziono żadnych produktów'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nie znaleziono żadnych produktów w koszu'),
            'all_items'          => __('Wszystkie produkty'),
        ],
        'public'                => true,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-admin-site',
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'taxonomies'            => ['products'],
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => __('katalog', 'company'),
            'pages' => true,
        ],
        'supports' => [
            'title',
            'page-attributes'
        ],
    ]);
}
```

**Custom Taxonomy**

```
add_action('init', 'registerCustomTaxonomies');
function registerCustomTaxonomies() {
    $taxonomySetup = [
        'label' => __('Kategorie produktów', 'company'),
        'has_archive' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => [
            'slug' => __('katalog', 'company'),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'with_front' => true
        ],
    ];
    register_taxonomy('products', ['product'], $taxonomySetup);
}

add_action('init', 'addTaxonomiesToPages');
function addTaxonomiesToPages() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('products', 'product');
}
```

I have created templates:

- taxonomy.php
- taxonomy-products.php
- category-products.php
- archive.php

And always returns index, why?

Comment: You're mixing up slugs and names. Inside your taxonomy your `register_taxonomy` you're calling it `products` and registering to the `product` post type, but when you register the post type you're setting its taxonomies to `katalog`, and then your setting the slugs for the taxonomy _and_ the post type to `katalog`, causing a conflict.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have change like you said (question updated) but still nothing. Same problem as earlier :/

Comment: is it because you set has_archive to false?

Comment: `has_archive` isn't actually an argument for `register_taxonomy()`, so wouldn't be doing anything.

Comment: @AlexOlder `true` or `false` - nothing.

Comment: Any another ideas?

Comment: `has_archive` definitely needs to be TRUE.  What have you hooked your `register_post_type()` function to?

Comment: @jdm2112 I set `has_archive` to both (taxonomy and cpt) to `true` but it still doesn't work. I have updated my question with full function for CPT

Comment: silly question but are you resetting your permalinks (visit settings/permalinks) after you make these changes?

Comment: @rudtek Everytime

Comment: Ok, I have clicked in many places and now I getting: for URL `/katalog/` I'm getting template from `archive.php` not `taxonomy-products.php` and for subcategories I'm getting error 404 - why?